# Postfix and rspamd: Disable bounce email

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, rspamd

How do I disable non-delivery notification (bounce mail) in Postfix?

I have setup Postfix 3.8.1 with rspamd 3.6. Spam filtering is working

```
admin@host123456:~ $ wget http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/gtube.txt -P /tmp
admin@host123456:~ $ sendmail user-part@my-domain.tld < /tmp/gtube.txt
```

results in

```
root@host123456:~ # egrep 4873D80B30 /var/log/mail.log
2023-10-28T21:41:00.297436+02:00 host123456 postfix/pickup[151929]: 4873D80B30: uid=1000 from=<admin>
2023-10-28T21:41:00.301825+02:00 host123456 postfix/cleanup[151958]: 4873D80B30: message-id=<GTUBE1.1010101@example.net>
2023-10-28T21:41:00.352027+02:00 host123456 postfix/cleanup[151958]: 4873D80B30: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 5.7.1 Gtube pattern; from=<admin@h2917298.stratoserver.net> to=<user-part@my-domain.tld>
2023-10-28T21:41:00.359127+02:00 host123456 postfix/cleanup[151958]: 4873D80B30: to=<user-part@my-domain.tld>, relay=none, delay=0.07, delays=0.07/0/0/0, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (Gtube pattern)
2023-10-28T21:41:00.365073+02:00 host123456 postfix/bounce[151960]: 4873D80B30: sender non-delivery notification: 58B2E81258
```

As you can see from the last log line postfix sends back a non-delivery notification to the original sender (in this case admin@host123456). How do I configure Postfix to simply reject spam mails?

Comment: This is false test. This mail could not have been rejected because it came via pickup service; in that case, there was no SMTP session where to reject to begin with. [Non-SMTPd milters **can never** reject mail.](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#non-smtp-milters) If the same mail comes via SMTP, there will be proper reject and no NDN will be generated.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for pointing this out. I gave it a try and submitted the test mail via a proper SMPT connection using `telnet my-mail-host.my-domain.tld 25` and indeed it worked. If you convert your comment into an answer I will accept it and you get the credits for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is no problem in your case. Your test uses so called *local* submission, which is injected into Postfix via its `pickup` service, in other words, it bypasses SMTP entirely. It's the "Local" path on the first diagram of the [Postfix Architecture Overview](https://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html).

The caveat here is that because there is no SMTP stage, there is no place where it is possible to actually reject the message before queuing it. This `sendmail` command is a user-level unprivileged application. It just creates a file in a specific place where anybody can write to and where (privileged) `pickup` daemon gets it from. The submission is already happened when the file is created and there is no way to signal any problems to the user other than to send them a non-delivery notification.

Milter technology first appeared in Sendmail package (not to be confused with `sendmail` command; Sendmail is a complete MTA like Postfix, and itself contains its own implementation of sendmail command which donated the name to the whole package) and meant to filter mail live **during active SMTP session**, so it *requires* one. It is the set of functions that are called at each stage of the session (e.g. after connection and after each user command and after each chunk of the message during DATA stage), and each of them can reject a message at any time. For messages that came in by other means (like local submission) Postfix can *simulate* the SMTP session for the milter to work properly by invoking these functions in the right order and with supposedly right "synthetic" arguments, but it still expects such milter to never reject messages because there is no real SMTP session where to report a reject. If your non-SMTP milter attempts to reject, Postfix will consider this as a configuration error. This was meant to sign mail generated on the server, not to filter it. Read more about this in the [Milter README](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#non-smtp-milters).

You just tested the wrong code path in Postfix, not the one incoming messages will take. If you try to deliver the same message via SMTP, milter will be in its full right to reject the message anytime and it will reject it before queue, so no non-delivery notification will be generated.